# jspdf not opening generated PDF(datauristring) in new tab in aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, aura, locker-service

I am trying to generate pdf and open it in a new tab using an aura component. Doing this with API version 50 gives me an error (due to locker service probably)

```
Uncaught SecureWindow.open supports http:, https:, mailto: schemes and relative urls.
```

I then reduced the api version to 39 to avoid the locker service and now a new tab does open but there's no content inside it. I see the errors :

```
This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue.
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://xxxxx.my.salesforce.com/services/proxy?*=1626960433931'
> (redirected from
> 'https://xxxxx.lightning.force.com/services/proxy?*=1626960433931')
> from origin 'https://xxxxx.lightning.force.com' has been blocked by
> CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource.

My Controller :

```
({
    doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
        console.log('Script loaded')
    },
    download: function (component, event, helper) {
        const rows = [{ Name: 'A', Role: "SF" }, { Name: 'B', Role: "SF" }, { Name: 'C', Role: "SF" }]
        let headers = helper.createHeaders(['Name', 'Role'])
        window.jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF
        const doc = new jsPDF()
        doc.table(30, 30, rows, headers, { autosize: true })
        console.log(doc.output('datauristring'));
        // doc.save('Test.pdf'); --> Works
        window.open(doc.output('datauristring')); --> Working only in firefox
        doc.output('dataurlnewwindow'); --> Not working at all
    },
})
```

The component :

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.jspdf}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"></ltng:require>
    <aura:attribute name="externalList" type="Array"></aura:attribute>
    <div>    
        <lightning:button label="generate aura pdf" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.download}">
        </lightning:button>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Copying the uristring manually and pasting it in another tab on chrome loads the pdf.

Any suggestions on making this work without using a VF page or an iframe ?